# Can you read a groups feed in Facebook using the Graph API?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I'm wondering if you can read a groups feed like you would with a user/page with the Graph API? I noticed that on the permissions page there's no permission regarding this, hence I was wondering whether it was even possible or not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For public groups, it can be accessed with no **access_token** required. But the non-public groups  can be accessed through "**user_groups**" permission. for more info, Check [Graph API Groups Access](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=195466193802264) link and [Permission settings](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/permissions/).

Comment: So it seems like even for open groups you need an access token? I think https://graph.facebook.com/GROUPID/feed should be the link to read the feed, yes ?

Comment: Try this 'graph.facebook.com/GROUP_ID/feed?access_token=YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN'

Comment: Yeah I tried that already and it worked! For the open group at least!

Comment: GROUP_ID/feed does not seem to work now. it returns an empty data array for every public group I've tried. do you know about any changes regarding this request?

Comment: Seems to be broken for me too.  I also get an empty array.

Comment: Same here - From the docs for the group-id/feed endpoint though (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.5/group/feed) it seems to suggest that just "A user access token for a member of the group." should suffice, however this does not seem to work.

I have added a similar comment to this related post - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19232117/facebook-open-graph-private-group-feed-request.

Answer (score 6):

As stated in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/31043823/5974754, the `user_groups` permission has been deprecated, and the Graph API can now only access data from open groups or groups that the user is *admin* of (using the `user_managed_groups` permission).

> https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.3
>
> **user_groups**
>
> Enables your app to read the Groups a person is a member of through
>   the groups edge on the User object.
>
> This permission does not allow you to create groups on behalf of a
>   person. It is not possible to create groups via the Graph API.
>
> **Review**
>
> If your app requests this permission Facebook will have to review how
>   your app uses it.
>
> **Limited Use**
>
> This permission is granted to apps building a Facebook-branded client
>   on platforms where Facebook is not already available. For example,
>   Android and iOS apps will not be approved for this permission. In
>   addition, Web, Desktop, in-car and TV apps will not be granted this
>   permission. In short: Facebook will no longer approve user_groups
>   permission for most developers starting from 30 Apr 2015.
>
> **In short: Facebook will no longer approve user_groups permission for most developers starting from 30 Apr 2015.**

Answer (score -1):

For open group:
We can access the group feeds using the app access token:
graph.facebook.com/v2.8/214858192201333?access_token=APP_ACCESS_TOKEN

For close group: 
If we try the same access token for close group:
graph.facebook.com/v2.8/1166669473345313?access_token=APP_ACCESS_TOKEN

We are getting :
{
   "error": {
      "message": "Unsupported get request. Object with ID '290683104317587' does not exist, cannot be loaded due to missing permiss
ions, or does not support this operation. Please read the Graph API documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api",
      "type": "GraphMethodException",
      "code": 100,
      "fbtrace_id": "D4vN/5Kdkhk"
   }
}

As I am member of the above group. When I use the user token in the same above request it worked.
We need to have the user access token. Like this below link is working for me:

graph.facebook.com/v2.8/GROUP_ID?access_token=USER_ACCESS_TOKEN
excerpts:
Posts from closed groups cannot usually be displayed for privacy reasons, but it’s sometimes possible to get around this by obtaining a “User” Access Token from Facebook from a user who is an admin of the group.

Any valid access token for a public group (i.e. the group's privacy setting is OPEN).