# Facebook open graph private group feed request

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

I want to get data from graph api, in particular I try to get timeline from a group. For example lets take a look at request provided on fb developers overview...

https://graph.facebook.com/195466193802264
this returns a json with group info as expected

https://graph.facebook.com/195466193802264/feed
this should return group's timeline, but I get the error below

{
    "error": {
       "message": "An access token is required to request this resource.",
       "type": "OAuthException",
       "code": 104
    }
 }

So I created a fb app (I suspected I will need to do this at the begining) and created an access token, but then I could not find any example how to send an access token together with get request, I only found an example how to send access token with a post request using curl. I even tried to fake a browser with python using mechanize and have logged in fb, and confirmed that I agree with apps permisions... again, where to put the token to get data??

I think this api is great, but documentation is just almost great, in the first video the guy tells you that using graph api is the same as making regular http requests, which it should be, but then please provide a working example how to do it...

So can someone please show me how to properly get access token with app key and secret and how to pass this token with the above request for a group's timeline? thank you very much

Comment: With GET requests, you just pass the access token as a parameter named `access_token` and the appropriate value.

Answer (score 4):

For GET requests, you just use a query string parameter:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/195466193802264/feed?access_token={access token}
```

As far as the access token, according to the [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/group/) you need:

To read a Group, you need:

- any valid access_token if the group is public (i.e. the group's
  privacy setting is OPEN)
- user_groups permission for a user's non-public groups
- friends_groups permission for a user's friend's non-public groups
- Groups for Apps and Games require the use of an App access_token.

Comment: Specifically for the group-id/feed endpoint though (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.5/group/feed) it suggests that just "A user access token for a member of the group." should suffice, however this does not seem to work.

Am I reading this wrong? Because it is underneath the group endpoint does it also need one of the permissions in your list above?

Comment: As stated in this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31043823/5974754), the `user_groups` permission has been deprecated, and the Graph API can now only access data from open groups or groups that the user is _admin_ of (using the `user_managed_groups` permission).