# Facebook Graph Api v2.0+ - /me/groups returns empty

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-graph-api-v2.2, facebook-group

I am trying to get my groups with graph api v2.0, but data returns empty:

```
{
  "data":  []
}
```

Before this I used v1.0 and this was workable. I use:
`https://graph.facebook.com/v2.2/252637181559106?fields=id%2cname&access_token=****`

Same result I have with https://apigee.com; (https://apigee.com/console/facebook?req=%7B%22resource%22%3A%22getusergroups%22%2C%22params%22%3A%7B%22query%22%3A%7B%7D%2C%22template%22%3A%7B%22user%22%3A%22me%22%7D%2C%22headers%22%3A%7B%7D%2C%22body%22%3A%7B%22attachmentFormat%22%3A%22mime%22%2C%22attachmentContentDisposition%22%3A%22form-data%22%7D%7D%2C%22verb%22%3A%22get%22%7D)

Can anyone help me to receive all my groups?

Answer (score 2):

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.3

> **user_groups**
>
> Enables your app to read the Groups a person is a member of through the groups edge on the User object.
>
> This permission does not allow you to create groups on behalf of a person. It is not possible to create groups via the Graph API.
>
> **Review**
>
> If your app requests this permission Facebook will have to review how your app uses it.
>
> **Limited Use**
>
> This permission is granted to apps building a Facebook-branded client on platforms where Facebook is not already available. For example, Android and iOS apps will not be approved for this permission. In addition, Web, Desktop, in-car and TV apps will not be granted this permission.

**In short: Facebook will no longer approve user_groups permission for most developers starting from 30 Apr 2015.**

Answer (score 1):

The group you are mentioning is a closed group.  In order to access anything about that group, you need to have the user_groups permission.  Facebook's policy is to deny that permission to ANYONE unless they are coding for a platform that does not have a native Facebook app.  If you are coding for Android iOS, or Windows Mobile, you are probably out of luck... =(

Comment: I have permission 'user_groups'. with API version v1.0 was worked

Comment: debug the access token. i am pretty sure you do NOT have user_groups authorized.

Comment: I have this permission because:
1. before April 30th 2015 it was workable;
2. if I haven't this permission then for request I should receive exception "Not have permission" but not HTTP/1.1 200 OK with empty object

Comment: No, you don’t. Go debug your access token via https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/ if you don’t believe it. And the result when the permission is missing _is_ just empty data, there is no error code returned or exception thrown in that case. ([Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer) will show a _debug message_ in that regard though if you ask it to.)

Comment: Ok, I check my app and I see what it was removed some permissions from 'Approved Items', but I not remove this items

Comment: user_groups was authorized in v1.0, but v1.0 expired on April 30th.  Even if you make calls to the v1.0 Graph API, Facebook will treat it as though you made the call to v2.0.  In v2.0, that permission is not authorized.  Even if you were using it in v1.0, Facebook has removed it in v2.0.