# fetch facebook group using Graph api java

Tags: java, facebook-graph-api, restfb, facebook-group

i am trying to get all groups from my facebook account using restfb in java, i wrote following code

```
JsonObject json = fbClient.fetchObject(userObj.getLong("id") + "/groups", JsonObject.class, Parameter.with("fields", "description,email,name));
```

when i check  my Json i am deting output  :

```
{
  "data":  []
}
```

i dont know  what is happening here when i try  to use Facebook graph Api Explorer it work fine and  display   all group available in Facebook account.

if an one can help me please.

Thanks

Comment: Can you show more of your code? How are `fbClient` and `userObj` setup?

Answer (score 0):

You can only get groups you manage, and you have to authorize with the `user_managed_groups` permission.

Most likely, you don´t manage any groups or the Access Token does not include the permission.

Comment: How  can u  authorize this permission?

Comment: you did not even implement a login process yet? in that case, you should start reading here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/

Answer (score 0):

As this answer describes, it is unlikely you will ever get permission to do what you want to do.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/31043823/1542667

> In short: Facebook will no longer approve user_groups permission for
>   most developers starting from 30 Apr 2015.

Answer (score 0):

How to get posts from Facebook groups using RestFB in Java?

I'm using `apptoken` to get posts in pages, but when I create the connection using `groupeId+"/post"` the program says:

```
Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:exec (default-cli) on project MonitoringFB:
    Command execution failed. Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1) -> [Help 1]

To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.

For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException"
```

What does this mean?